# Its possible to add a header for a Form.List?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have this component but this list does not have a header i need one.

It's a list i would like to put a header like a table.

```
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Button, Form, Input, Space } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';
const App = () => {
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log('Received values of form:', values);
  };
  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
          <>
            {fields.map(({ key, name, ...restField }) => (
              <Space
                key={key}
                style={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  marginBottom: 8,
                }}
                align="baseline"
              >
                <Form.Item
                  {...restField}
                  name={[name, 'first']}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: 'Missing first name',
                    },
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                  {...restField}
                  name={[name, 'last']}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: 'Missing last name',
                    },
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                </Form.Item>
                <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(name)} />
              </Space>
            ))}
            <Form.Item>
              <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => add()} block icon={<PlusOutlined />}>
                Add field
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </>
        )}
      </Form.List>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
export default App;
```

This code I took from https://4x.ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-items

It's possible to put a header, that header should to be resposive like the column from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Form.List itself doesn't support adding headers like a table. But you can add it manually. Check below structure

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';

const MyForm = () => {
  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form">
      {/* Add a header here */}
      <div className="form-list-header">
        <h3>Your Form List Header</h3>
        {/* Any other header content */}
      </div>

      <Form.List
        name="names"
        // Rest of the Form.List properties
      >
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
          <>
            {fields.map((field, index) => (
              // Render your dynamic form items here
              <Form.Item
                // Form.Item properties
              >
                <Input placeholder="Input field" />
              </Form.Item>
            ))}
            <Form.Item>
              <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => add()} block>
                Add Item
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </>
        )}
      </Form.List>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default MyForm;
```

Comment: Its base on how you design